# Google Assistant Personal Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have created an action inside google, connected it to dialogflow, connected in byt fulfillment to my own home network.

Now I would like to be able to use this on my phone, raspberry, etc. But I don`t want to deploy this to the whole world (because then they can turn off my lights).

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can release your action to an Alpha channel, which let's you control who can access your action, which is just yourself by default. But you can also add up to twenty accounts.

https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments

Comment: Thanks already for your help.. I did the alpha deployment, the status is deployed. But I still need to call my action before I can use the commands on my phone.. can you what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to build a smart home application that you can directly control you should visit developers.google.com/smarthome

Comment: Nice page, but for now I only want every Google assistant request going by my own API.. and this for a select list of devices (personal ones only).

Comment: If you want to do it the current way, you will need to invoke your action before giving a command, or create a shortcut in the Assistant settings.

Comment: Yes I see now. No way to release this version just for my devices? Needed to change my profile language to English before I could use the opt link. But still I need to open in manually so no hands free call for ok Google with my own commands without releasing my version.?

Comment: You should have at least an alpha version, which will work just for your devices unless you want to invite someone else.

Comment: Ok, but I can only use this when asking Google to talk to my action.. then it switched over.. but I don't want that step in the middle, I would like to remove this step and call my own API directly after calling ok Google without first asking to talk to my action.. is this possible?

Comment: Then you should build a smart home application

Comment: I think I will try it out.. I hoped it would be possible to just redirect every question direct after ok Google to my own server.. but since it isn't possible I will try smart home.. thanks

Comment: @Josjr87, you can goto dialogflow console than goto integration tab than click google assistant integration setting, in that you will find implicit invocation in that you can mention any intent that you want to invoke directly without saying "talk to my xyz"